# Javascript Regex for serverName:port

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the best regex that I can use for client validation of URLs of the form;

```
example.com:8080 (Valid)
10.15.123.14:8080 (Valid)
example.com (Invalid)
10.15.123.14 (Invalid)
```

The protocol "http" is not necessary/required. In fact that is not going to part of my form field.

Comment: What about `/:[1-9][0-9]*$/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like this `/^([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]+\:[1-9][0-9]+$/i`

```
var str = [
    "Example.com:8080",
    "10.15.123.14:8080",
    "example.com",
    "10.13.123.14",
    "example!1.com:8080",
    "example-1.com:8080",
    "example!1.com:8080",
    "example\1.com:8080",
    "example1.com:8"
    ];

var regex = /^([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]+\:[1-9][0-9]+$/i;

for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    $('#test').append(regex.test(str[i])+"</br>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/2SnhP/5/

Comment: This would also match `google.com:0`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo true.. hmmm... I'll improve it :)

Comment: ..now all you need is just anchors as without them you'd match `:) I know a website: google.com:8080 is a website you DO NOT WANT TO GO TO`.

Comment: It is also matching example!1.com:8080 ....I want the only valid special characters as hyphen and dot...Also port number should be numeric 2-4 chars

Comment: why is it matching `!`?????

Comment: I just tested on http://jsfiddle.net/2SnhP/4/

Comment: @testndtv ah, it wasn't matching from the start of the string. it's fixed now.

Comment: Don't say I didn't warn you: "*now all you need is just anchors*" ;)

Comment: @h2ooooooo lol, I was too busy in fiddle and missed that and I even upvoted it. I need more coffee.

Comment: Thx a lot..just a single issue now..the port number should be between 2-4 numeri chars...so :8 and :80808 should be invalid

Comment: @testndtv change `:[1-9][0-9]+` to `:[1-9][0-9]{1,4}`

Answer (score 3):

Matches ip's until 255.255.255.255 and ports until 65535:

```
^((([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])|[a-zA-Z0-9]*):(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]\d|65[0-4](\d){2}|6[0-4](\d){3}|[1-5](\d){4}|[1-9](\d){0,3})$
```

Matches websites (or ip's) and ports until 65535:

```
^[^:]+:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]\d|65[0-4](\d){2}|6[0-4](\d){3}|[1-5](\d){4}|[1-9](\d){0,3})$
```

Comment: +1 for effort, but it'd be **way** better just parsing the string without regex.